# Does Google Cloud Platform and its Applications are GDPR Compliants?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gdprconsentform

My first question here and it's related to GDPR with GCP. Even though I have found some useful information from the Community, I still couldn't find any confirmative information.

I live in Europe and I'm afraid my application using GCP - including Firebase and App Engine - might need some additional configuration due to GDPR. Do you guys know any reference or articles that mention - or even applications - that confirms that using these applications won't need any further configuration regarding GDPR compliance?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60314881/support-us-region-appengine-project-with-gdpr-complaint

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about managing a business relationship, communicating between the question OP and a third party, and/or dealing with a legal issue. In other words, it's not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic]. You might be able to get help from the Customer Service for the company you are interfacing with. If you want an interpretation of legal requirements, it might be appropriate to ask on [law.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major areas to GDPR:

- The services you are using.
- Your applications and their management of data.

Google Cloud is GDPR compliant provided you implement/deploy Google Cloud services correctly.

Your applications and their management of data are not GDPR compliant just because GCP is compliant. You must implement policies and procedures to attain GDPR compliance and maintain compliance.

Compliance with the various standards and requirements is very complicated and challenging. This cannot be answered in the space that Stack Overflow supports. There are substantial books written on these topics.

An example reference is:

[The EU General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR): A Practical Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319579584)

> Do you guys know any reference or articles that mention - or even
>   applications - that confirms that using these applications won't need
>   any further configuration regarding GDPR compliance?

Compliance is not a software program that tests your application. It is a set of guidelines and requirements that must be reviewed/verified. As I mentioned this is a substantial amount of work to claim compliance.

If you are looking for a quick guide to GDPR look at this book. This is suitable for getting started, but in no way covers everything you need to know.

[GDPR - Fix it Fast: Apply GDPR to Your Company in 10 Simple Steps](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0993478859)

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley ! Really appreciate your answer! It was very clear and helped me understand better.